# reduce battery consumption of foreground-service

Tags: android, android-service

My application starts a service witch is set to foreground by calling `startForeground()`, because the service was canceled quite often before. Since I added `startForeground()` the app has a high battery consumption.

```
while (!stop){
    if ((System.currentTimeMillis()-prevMillis) >= intervalSerivce) {
       //get some HTML code and extract a value, if condition fulfilled call a funtion
    }
```

}

The interval is just **30min** to **60min**, depending on the value, got by the code inside the if-condition. I think this couldn't be so energy-intensive.

Should I use `sleep()` instead of `currentTimeMillis()`? 
What have I to consider additionally?

Comment: I don't know if this can be helpful at your case, but i use `long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5 * 1000` (five seconds delay) in one of my projects and works fine, no batt consumption. Also: are you sure you have to have it foreground? I call my service as an Intent. Luck.

Comment: More code please

Comment: Before having the service in the foreground, it was canceled quite often. Which alternative do you suggest @statosdotcom? The services main code (see loop above) is send to an Executor by executor.execute(). Most import is that the service runs non-stop or at least restarts a few seconds after beeing canceled.